# Why redirection to stdout and stdin so common in PIPE programming

Tags: c, pipe

I am very much new to IPC programming in C. I had a very basic question, why many of our C codes use dup2 to make stdout as write head and stdin as read head for the PIPE. Is there any benefit, comapred to an array of integer type and using the array as an input to pipe call?

Comment: The major reason is when creating a new process and executing another application, because the new application will not know about the pipes but do know about standard input and output.

Comment: I see your point. So most of our programs o/p to stdout and take i/p from stdin. So if my pipe program [|] uses stdin and stdout as write head and read head of the UNIX pipe then purpose served for passing the information between two irrelevant code pieces. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many C programs are written as filters, which (by default) read from standard input and write to standard output.  The plumbing with pipes exploits, and supports, idioms of sending the output from one program to the input of another, as with:

```
ls | wc -l
```

That's why you very often end up with code connecting the pipe file descriptors to standard input or standard output.  If you needed to make programs read from, or write to, arbitrary file descriptors, you'd have to supply control arguments to tell them what to do.  Granted, these days on systems such as Linux with the `/dev/fd` file system, it would be doable, but that's a recent innovation that was not available when many programs were first written.  You could get nearly the same result as above using:

```
ls | wc -l /dev/fd/0
```

but `wc` would echo the file name in this case, whereas it does not echo the file name when no name is given as in the first example.

Comment: Thanks ... it explains. Very basic but I miss this small information from the pages I am reading :) Thank you.